# Least code to write this with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

normally I'm a backend developer, so I'm not really good with javascript and jQuery. I have 3 radio buttons, and I want to display an image next to the radio button that has been checked. Currently I'm doing it like this with javascript. Every radio button has an `onClick` method that passes the id as parameter. Then the method does this.

```
function toggle(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.id == 'rechnung0') {
        document.getElementById('rechnung0').style.cssText= 'display:block;float:right;';
        document.getElementById('rechnung1').style.cssText= 'display:none;float:right;';
        document.getElementById('rechnung2').style.cssText= 'display:none;float:right;';
    }
    if(e.id == 'rechnung1') {
        document.getElementById('rechnung0').style.cssText= 'display:none;float:right;';
        document.getElementById('rechnung1').style.cssText= 'display:block;float:right;';
        document.getElementById('rechnung2').style.cssText= 'display:none;float:right;';
    }
    if(e.id == 'rechnung2') {
        document.getElementById('rechnung0').style.cssText= 'display:none;float:right;';
        document.getElementById('rechnung1').style.cssText= 'display:none;float:right;';
        document.getElementById('rechnung2').style.cssText= 'display:block;float:right;';
    }
}
```

But there must be a faster way with jQuery. Isn't there one? Like, when one of the radio_buttons gets selected. the name is `billingaddress`, then everyone of the group which is't selected gets the css with display none, and everyone of the group that is selcted gets the block style.

How is this possible with jquery?

Comment: `e.id` is the same as `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function toggle(id) {
    $('#rechnung0,#rechnung1,#rechnung2').css('float', 'right').css('display', function () {
        return this.id == id ? 'block' : 'none'
    })
}
```

If you can provide more context to the code, we may be able to help you more

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $('input:radio').click(function () {
        $('input:radio').not(this).prop('checked', false).next('img').hide();
        $(this).next('img').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/349Rx/1/

This assumes that your image is actually an `<img>` and located close to the radio button in your DOM. Also, it doesn't require the onclick to be set on the radiobuttons.

Comment: `closest` can't be right. You can't have a radio button inside an image element.

Comment: @Barmar You are absolutely right! Updated my answer with `.next()` :)

Answer (score 1):

give all of your radio buttons a similar class, and a data attribute

```
<input type='radio' class='radio' data-id='1' />
<input type='radio' class='radio' data-id='2' />
<input type='radio' class='radio' data-id='3' />

<img id="1" style="display:none; " />
<img id="2" style="display:none; " />
<img id="3" style="display:none; " />

$(document).ready(function()){
    $(".radio").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $("#"+id).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the arrangement is like "radio + img", "radio + img", "radio + img", etc. This can be done with css ***without js***.

**css:**

```
input[name=toggleImg]:not(:checked) + img {
    display : none;
}

input[name=toggleImg]:checked + img {
    display : inline;
}
```

**html:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<input type="radio" name="toggleImg" />
<img src="img/img (1).jpg"/>
<input type="radio" name="toggleImg" />
<img src="img/img (2).jpg"/>
<input type="radio" name="toggleImg" />
<img src="img/img (3).jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #rechnung0, #rechnung1, #rechnung2{display:none;float:right;}
</style>
```

**JS**

```
function toggle(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    document.getElementById('rechnung0').style.display= 'none;';
    document.getElementById('rechnung1').style.display= 'none;';
    document.getElementById('rechnung2').style.display= 'none;';

    if(e.id == 'rechnung0') {
        document.getElementById('rechnung0').style.display= 'block;';
    }
    else if(e.id == 'rechnung1') {
        document.getElementById('rechnung1').style.display= 'block;';
    }
    else if(e.id == 'rechnung2') {
        document.getElementById('rechnung2').style.display= 'block;';
    }
```